# Groovy: inconsistent behaviour between for loop and each loop when using Future

Tags: for-loop, groovy, concurrency

I recently stumble upon this interesting groovy feature.

I have a list of objects, and try to loop through each of them.

Inside each loop a Callable is instantiated and its only purpose is to return a property of the looping object, the Callable is then submitted to a ThreadPool to return a Future object.

Each property is later obtained by corresponding Future object.

The problem is that the result varies when I use different looping method, see below code:

```
package tmp


import java.util.concurrent.*

class TestCode {

    public static final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)

    static void main(String[] args) {
        normal()
        abnormal()
        System.exit(0)

    }

    static void normal(){
        SomeInfo info1 = new SomeInfo(on: '001')
        SomeInfo info2 = new SomeInfo(on: '002')
        List<SomeInfo> infos = [info1,info2]

        List<Future<String>> futureList = new ArrayList<>()
        infos.each {SomeInfo info ->
            Future<String> future = executorService.submit(new Callable<String>() {
                @Override
                String call() throws Exception {
                    return info.getOn()
                }
            })
            futureList.add(future)
        }
        futureList.each {
            def get = it.get()
            println "normal get="+get
        }
    }

    static void abnormal(){
        SomeInfo info1 = new SomeInfo(on: '001')
        SomeInfo info2 = new SomeInfo(on: '002')
        List<SomeInfo> infos = [info1,info2]

        List<Future<String>> futureList = []
        for(SomeInfo info:infos){
            Future<String> future = executorService.submit(new Callable<String>() {
                @Override
                String call() throws Exception {
                    return info.getOn()
                }
            })
            futureList.add(future)
        }
        futureList.each {
            def get = it.get()
            println "abnormal get="+get
        }
    }

    private static class SomeInfo{
        private String on

        String getOn() {
            return on
        }

        void setOn(String on) {
            this.on = on
        }
    }
}
```

the ouput is as such:

```
normal get=001
normal get=002
abnormal get=002
abnormal get=002
```

The only difference between `normal()` method and `abnormal()` method is the use of loop.

The `each` loop produces the correct result.

The `for` loop produces the incorrect result, as if somehow the Callable in each loop step is seeing the same object.

And what is the cause of this?

Tested in groovy2, groovy3 and groovy4

The probem remains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a scoping problem to me.

The `info` instance in code

```
Future<String> future = executorService.submit(new Callable<String>() {
                @Override
                String call() throws Exception {
                    return info.getOn()
                }
            })
```

in case of the for-loop refers to rather "global" loop-scoped variable, so all Futures get the last actual value.

The Groovy's `forEach` on the other hand uses the closure-bound object and work fine.

In general, I would rewrite your iteration block to be idiomatic Groovy like so:

```
List<Future<String>> futureList = infos.collect{ info -> executorService.submit info.&getOn }
```

Comment: it's definitely a scoping issue. in `for(info:infos){...}` the `info` declared outside of future creation code block, when in `each{info->...}` the `info` is like a local variable of the code block. just make this change to a "for" option to make it similar to "each" `for(_info:infos){ def info=_info; ...}`